# How to dynamically Add and Remove multiple <tr> with input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

What i m trying to do is when the user type number quantity automatically jquery must create that number of  with inputs.

so i used this code to generate

```
$( "#cont_qty" ).change(function() 
{   
    var cont_qty = this.value;
    for(var i=1 ; cont_qty>i; i++)
    {
    itemCount++;
    // dynamically create rows in the table
       var auto_tr = '<tr id="tr'+itemCount+'"><td><input class="input-medium" type="text" id="cont_no'+itemCount+'" name="cont_no'+itemCount+'" value=""></td></tr>';      

       $("#munna").append(auto_tr)
    }
});
```

If the user type 5 then it creates 4  now if the user change the value and type 7 then have to remove the previous created those 4  and then have to create 6

now i dont know how to remove

Comment: $("#munna").html(html);

Comment: sorry for confusing now changed it  @atmd

Comment: @BhojendraNepal yes its working, i dont know what to do When user again change the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Empty before looping, and start at zero

```
$( "#cont_qty" ).change(function()  {   
    var cont_qty = this.value;

    $("#munna").empty();

    for(var i=0 ; cont_qty>i; i++) {
       itemCount++;
       var auto_tr = '<tr id="tr'+itemCount+'"><td><input class="input-medium" type="text" id="cont_no'+itemCount+'" name="cont_no'+itemCount+'" value=""></td></tr>';      

       $("#munna").append(auto_tr)
    }
});
```

Comment: for some reasons adeneo always finds a faster and clearer way. .empty() is definetly the most intuitive solution.

Comment: @briosheje - thank you, if I was doing this i would probably use `$.map` to iterate and return `$('<tr />` inside an `append`, that way the DOM was only changed once, and it was a lot more jQuery'ish. I felt like that changed the question too much, sometimes just fixing the OP's code is what he'll learn the most from.

Comment: Nice. I always forget about .empty()

Comment: @adeneo: indeed, didn't even thing about the $.map, but it's in fact faster even if for some may not be the clearest thing in this universe :P

Answer (score 1):

use **Html()** not **append()**

```
$("#cont_qty").change(function () {
    var cont_qty = this.value;
    var html = "";
    for (var i = 1; cont_qty >= i; i++) {
        itemCount++;
        // dynamically create rows in the table
        html += '<tr id="tr' + itemCount + '"><td><input class="input-medium" type="text" id="cont_no' + itemCount + '" name="cont_no' + itemCount + '" value=""></td></tr>';
    }
    $("#munna").html(html);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `.html()` instead of `.append()` outside of your loop.

```
$("#munna").html(html);
```

Instead of

```
$("#munna").append(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#cont_qty" ).change(function() 
{   
    var cont_qty = this.value;
    var html = '';
    for(var i=1 ; cont_qty>i; i++)
    {
    itemCount++;
    // dynamically create rows in the table
    html += '<tr id="tr'+itemCount+'"><td><input class="input-medium" type="text" id="cont_no'+itemCount+'" name="cont_no'+itemCount+'" value=""></td></tr>';     

    }
    $("#munna").html(html);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent it from creating one less than you want, change this:

```
for(var i=1 ; cont_qty>i; i++)
```

to this:

```
for(var i=1 ; i<=cont_qty; i++)
```

And, has already been stated, as you want to reset the amount of fields everytime you change the number, change `$("#munna").append(html);` to `$("#munna").html(html);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#cont_qty" ).change(function() 
{   
    var cont_qty = this.value;
    for(var i=1 ; cont_qty>i; i++)
    {
    itemCount++;

    html += '<tr id="tr'+itemCount+'"><td><input class="input-medium" type="text" id="cont_no'+itemCount+'" name="cont_no'+itemCount+'" value=""></td></tr>';     
    }

    $("#munna").html(html)
});
```

Beside of use 'append' the html div, .html can reload the div content.

Answer (score 0):

change the whole html content of #munna with html()

```
$( "#cont_qty" ).change(function() 
    {   
        var cont_qty = this.value;
        for(var i=1 ; cont_qty>i; i++)
        {
        itemCount++;
        // dynamically create rows in the table
           var auto_tr += '<tr id="tr'+itemCount+'"><td><input class="input-medium" type="text" id="cont_no'+itemCount+'" name="cont_no'+itemCount+'" value=""></td></tr>';      

        }
         $("#munna").html(auto_tr)
    });
```